# Creating SandBoxed WebPart for SharePoint Online

Tags: office365

I have signed up for office 365 preview site. I need to create a Sandboxed WebPart for the site. Can you tell me, Do I need SharePoint 2013 installed on my system? When I try to create SharePoint project 2013 it shows me that I need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build SharePoint fulltrust or sandboxed solutions you need SharePoint on your development system.

If you're going to build an SharePoint 2013 App, you don't need SharePoint on your development system.

You should review the various architectures and then decide which type of solution you create.Best starting point is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/